# A error for Ambiguous use of "Task" in alamofire source

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ambiguous

when i import alamofire source, everything was normal at first,but after i add a create a Bridging-Header file to project, error occurred:
[see error picturs please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZQKq.png) 
and i try to remove bridge file and reset build setting->objective-C Bridging Header is empty.

Xcode Version: 8.3.3(8E3004b)

Alamofire 4.0

but still not work , thank you for your help.

i'm sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the reason for bridge file.

Comment: yes i'm sure it's swift, i added bridge file in order use system extern func I CC_MD5, i had remove it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bug of alamofire . it will be solved in version Alamofire 4.1.0.

> This issue is fixed in the master branch and will be released shortly
>   as Alamofire 4.1.0.

[Source](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1779)

Comment: thank you for your message , Is there a temporary way to fix this problem?

Comment: How to add alamofire in your project ?

Comment: Add the source directory to the project directly.

Comment: mean alamofire project ?

Comment: not project ,only source code , Alamofire-master/source

Comment: i‘m sure my opeator way same to that link, and firstly it is work OK, after add bridge error occurred.

Comment: Is it the problem of my local environment?

Comment: can i send my test project to you see it ?

Comment: there is no  git on my  macbook  now , can i send code to your email?

Comment: alamofire not imported as i suggested in your project.